# Proper way of chaining operations in redux thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using `redux thunk` first time. What is proper way of chaining operations?

I want to fetch location after user input is given and when there is response with data from `Google Maps API`, then I want to immediately use that data to fetch weather for that location.
`Redux thunk` is working, but only for first operation (fetching location). 
`Data2` in `request2` is always `undefined`, can you tell me why is that?

```
 export function fetchLocation(city) {
      const urlGoogle = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${city}&key=${API_KEY_GOOGLE}`;
      const request = axios.get(urlGoogle);

      return (dispatch) => {
        request.then(({ data }) => {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_LOCATION, payload: data });

          const lat = data.results["0"].geometry.location.lat;
          const lng = data.results["0"].geometry.location.lng;
          const urlWunder = `https://api.wunderground.com/api/${API_KEY_WUNDERGROUND}/forecast10day/q/${lat},${lng}.json`;

          console.log(urlWunder); // Link is ok, it works in browser

          const request2 = axios.get(urlWunder);
          request2.then(({ data2 }) => {
            console.log('Data2', data2);  // Getting undefined, why ?
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_WEATHER, payload: data2 });
          });
        });
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the second request isn't returning a field named, say, `response.data2`, so when you destructure it, `data2` will be undefined.  You probably still need to look for a field named `data`, but give it a different local parameter name, like:  `request2.then({data : data2})`.